# Cannot create steam game folder "new steam folder must be mounted on a file system with execute permission"

Tags: steam, linux

I created a partition on my second hard drive for steam games. I added a steam library there and successfully downloaded a few games. After I rebooted, the library disappeared. I tried to add it again but I always get the error `new steam folder must be mounted on a file system with execute permission`. I have seen a bunch of posts about this but my problem is different for 2 reasons:

1. Other solutions are for ntfs. My partition is ext4.
2. Other solutions suggest renaming `SteamApps` to `steamapps`. I already have `steamapps`.

Here is the relevant line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=8c6ead8f-bf5f-41b9-864e-d743ad374636 /run/media/marcel/games  ext4    defaults,exec,user,nofail             0 0
```

The partiton gets mounted to `/run/media/marcel/games`. `/run/media/marcel/` and everything under it is owned by `marcel:marcel`. `/run/media/marcel`, `/run/media/marcel/games`, and `/run/media/marcel/games/steamapps` are `755`. Everything seems to be executable by steam.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Zeus 4.14.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 3 07:02:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Steam version:

```
steam 1.0.0.54-3
```

Comment: This is a little bit too "Super User" level to really fit in the Gaming QA.  You can generalize it to "application error: does not have execution permission in a mounted volume".  Then go into details.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to move my post or do I have to repost?

Comment: You can edit it, copy everything, delete the question, and repost.  Reposting is bad only if you keep the duplicates.  There's nothing stopping you from deleting the question.

Answer (score 3):

The order of options in `/etc/fstab` is important and `user` sets `noexec`. Since I had `exec` before `user`, the `noexec` from `user` took precedence over explicit `exec`. `/etc/fstab` should be changed to:

```
 UUID=8c6ead8f-bf5f-41b9-864e-d743ad374636 /run/media/marcel/games  ext4    defaults,user,nofail,exec             0 0
```